# Use legacy conflict resolution view in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

After the June (or July) 2022 update, the merge conflict view no longer looks like the one in the documentation: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/versioncontrol#_merge-conflicts

I do not like the new 3-way view at all. Is there any way to go back to the previous merge conflict view (as it appears in the above documentation link)?

I tried adding the following to settings.json, but the result was no diff decoration at all:

`"git.mergeEditor": false,`

**UPDATE:**

For anyone who comes across this, the following combination has resolved this issue for me and others who have commented below.

```
"diffEditor.codeLens": true,
"git.mergeEditor": false,
```

Comment: thank you for posting this, that new view is nightmarishly complicated compared to this

Comment: yes, completely nightmare such a change.

Comment: The last combination works for me, thanks a lot!!